# Which elasticsearch node type should be used to insert/query data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch cluster formed from:

- 2x master nodes:

```
node.master: true
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
```

- 4x client nodes on which kibana is running:

```
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
```

- 6x data nodes

```
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
```

My question is which elasticsearch node type should I provide to client to insert/query data into/from the cluster?

I have read elasticsearch docs but did not find anything saying that I should use particular node type.

Comment: why do you have 4x just for Kibana ? and 2x master ? about nodes, you need to use all data+master nodes repartition will be handle by elastic

Comment: I inherited this setup after someone ;) 4 nodes because of 2 data centers ( 2 nodes 1st data center + 2 nodes 2nd data center.

Answer (score 0):

2 master nodes is not ideal, there's no majority if you loose one of them! and 4 client nodes for Kibana is excessive

I would suggest;

- 3 master only nodes
- 2 client nodes that are ingest nodes as well, to send data to
- however many data nodes you want

Comment: I forgot to mention there are two data centers. I don’t know why they had setup cluster in such way. So now I have two different opinions which nodes should by used to insert/query data.

Comment: one cluster across 2 DCs is not a great cluster